# js doesnot get applied to appended html

Tags: javascript, animation, dynamic, partial-views

I am having slick slide effect on the divs using .js file as shown below.

```
<div id="thumblist" class="lazy slider">
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

So, on initial load it applies the slide effect to images. But after I call ajax and append the data in 'thumblist' div, it shows the html but then .js effect doesn't get apllied to it.  How to solve this issue?

Comment: You must "reinit" slider after DOM changes. Which slider/plugin do you use?

Comment: yes you must **reinit** slider after dom changes.

Comment: I am just using one .js file... slick.min.js and  function $(".lazy").slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand', // ondemand progressive anticipated
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,

      });  how to reinitialize?

Comment: I am using lazy loading of slick slider.. here is the refrence http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Reinitialize of script is required. But at the same time we first have to destroy the slick effect and then to the whole data apply slick.

```
$(".lazy").slick('unslick');

..... append data .....

$(".lazy").slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand', // ondemand progressive anticipated
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrows: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,

});
```